# How to properly have a search page with multiple filters?

Tags: php, laravel

Im with some doubts about how to create a search page like below where the user can serch for congresses using multiple filters (category, city, price, date) and pagination. So I have a search.blade.php page like this:

[image]

For now I created a SearchController with that returns the congresses, the cities and categories to the view search.blade.php:

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $pageLimit = 1;
        return view('search')
            ->with('categories', Category::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get())
            ->with('cities', Congress::orderBy('created_at','desc')->pluck("city")->unique())
            ->with('congresses', Congress::orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate($pageLimit));
    }
}
```

So in search.blade.php there are this select menus:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
        <form>
            <select class="custom-select form-control">
                <option selected="">All categories </option>
                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                    <option {value="{{ $category->id }}">
                        {{ $category->name }}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
        <form>
            <select class="custom-select form-control">
                <option selected="">All cities</option>
                @foreach($cities as $city)
                    <option>
                        {{ $city }}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
        <form>
            <select class="custom-select form-contro">
                <option selected="">Price</option>
                <option>Paid</option>
                <option>Free</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
        <form>
            <select class="custom-select form-control">
                <option selected="">This week</option>
                <option>This month</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in search.blade.php appear also by default the last 8 inserted congresses:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($congresses as $congress)
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 my-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{$congress->image}}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="font-size-sm">{{$congress->start_date}}</p>
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{$congress->name}}</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
    {{$congresses->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
</div>
```

Do you know how what is necessary so this context can be properly achived?

Comment: maybe create an array of filters, pass that into model and build condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

**search.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="{{ route('your.index') }}" method="get">
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
            <select class="custom-select form-control" name="category_id">
                <option selected="" value="">All categories </option>
                @foreach ($categories as $category)
                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ (!empty($categoryId) && $categoryId == $category->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                        {{ $category->name }}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 mb-4 mb-md-0">
            <select class="custom-select form-control" name="city">
                <option selected="" value="">All cities</option>
                @foreach($cities as $city)
                    <option value="{{ $city }}" {{ (!empty($selectedCity) && $selectedCity == $city) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                        {{ $city }}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
            <select class="custom-select form-contro" name="price">
                <option {{ empty($price) ? 'selected' : '' }} value="">Price</option>
                <option value="paid" {{ (!empty($price) && $price == 'paid') ? 'selected' : '' }}>Paid</option>
                <option value="free" {{ (!empty($price) && $price == 'free') ? 'selected' : '' }}>Free</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
            <select class="custom-select form-control" name="range">
                <option value="week" {{ (!empty($range) && $range == 'week') ? 'selected' : '' }}>This week</option>
                <option  value="month" {{ (!empty($range) && $range == 'month') ? 'selected' : '' }}>This month</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Search

**Controller**

```
class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request){
        $categoryId = $request->get('category_id');
        $city       = $request->get('city');
        $price      = $request->get('price');
        $range      = $request->get('range');
        $pageLimit  = 1;

        $congress = Congress::Query();

        if(!empty($categoryId)) {
            //$congress = $congress->where('category_id', $categoryId)
            $congress = $congress->whereHas('categories', function($qry) use($categoryId) {
                $qry->where('category_id', categoryId);
            });
        }

        if(!empty($city)) {
            $congress = $congress->where('city', $city)
        }

        if(!empty($price)) {
            if($price == "free") { 
                $congress = $congress->whereHas('ticketTypes', function($qry) { 
                    $qry->where('price', '=', 0); 
                }); 
            } elseif($price == "paid") { 
                $congress = $congress->whereHas('ticketTypes', function($qry) { 
                    $qry->where('price', '>', 0); 
               }); 
           } 
        }

        if(!empty($range)) {
            if($range == "week") {
                 $congress = $congress->where('start_date', '<', Carbon::now()->addDays(7));
            } elseif($range == "month") {
                 $congress = $congress->where('start_date', '<', <arbon::now()->addDays(30));
            }
        }

        $congress = $congress->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate($pageLimit);

        return view('search', [
            'categories'     => Category::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(),
            'cities'         => Congress::orderBy('created_at','desc')->pluck("city")->unique(),
            'congresses'     => $congress,
            'categoryId'     => $categoryId,
            'selectedCity'   => $city,
            'price'          => $price,
            'range'          => $range,
        ];
    }
}
```

You may customise this with your real requirements and real variables.

For paginating the results with the filter options, use paginate links like the following:

```
<div class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
    {{$congresses->appends(Request::all())->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
</div>
```

Hope it helps.. Let me know the results..

Comment: Thanks, in the SearchController is  "            'city'           => $city,  or "            'city'           => $cityId,
"?
"

Comment: It appears "Trying to get property of non-object (" in  <?php $__currentLoopData = $cities; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $city): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo e($city->id); ?>" <?php echo e((!empty($cityId) && $cityId == $city->id) ? 'selected' : ''); ?>>
                                            <?php echo e($city); ?> with "$cityId".

Comment: Update city select with the following.. `<option value="{{ $city }}" {{ (!empty($cityId) && $cityId == $city) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                        {{ $city }}
                    </option>`

Comment: Thanks, now it dont appears any error. But it seems that is not working. For example the user is in the search page (search.blade.php). There are 3 congresses in the database, 2 are associated with category that has the id "1". The other congress is associated with category that has id "2". When the user acesses the search page it appears the 3 congresses (I change the page limit to 5), if the user selects the category with id "1" the page is not refreshed it still appears all congresses and not only the 2 congresses that are associated with category that has id "1".

Comment: You don't have a button? If not add a submit button. Or if you don't want search button then add change event for form elements and submit form via js.

Comment: Thanks, is necessary to have a change event for each select menu?

Comment: Try this answer with a submit button. If it works then we will go for the js method.

Comment: Thanks, but so is necessary to have a form with a submit button for each select menu?

Comment: No. One submit button would be enough. I will update the answer with that. But user should have to click that button after all filter options and click that button. Further update will be based on success of this method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171393/discussion-between-ab-ab-and-jow).

Answer (score 0):

use querybuilder and concatenate each property you want to associate in search.